# Optimise Hive Query in order to avoid exceeded GC timeout exception

Tags: exception, optimization, garbage-collection, hive

I am running a query in Hive which is pretty straight forward but I am continuously exceeded GC timeout and OOM errors,

Query is of the form

select a.field1 -- selecting about 30 cols!
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.field2 = t2.field2 and t1.date = '20120801'
join table2 t3 on t1.field7 = t2.field2 and t1.date = '20120801'

I am selecting about 30 fields from this query. table1 is partitioned by date and contains around 300,000 records. table2 contains about 100 records.

Is there some way I can optimise this query?

Answer (score 0):

Been playing around with Mapjoin for hours and finally got it to work

Added the hint SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(t2,t3)*/

Query now runs in a few seconds